# Cutting a shape from a VRT file with GDAL warp

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, vrt

I have a couple of overlapping TIFF files which I want first to merge and then to clip a shapefile from the result TIFF. The problem is that the TIFFs are pretty big and when the TIFFs are overlapping the merge process is really slow.

I discovered the VRT format so I made a virtual raster from the TIFF files but after I clip the shape from it the result TIFF can not be opened in QGIS for example.

Is it possible at all to clip a shape from a VRT?

Here is the command I'm trying.

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -dstnodata -999 -cutline my_shape.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha virtual.vrt cliped.tif
```

Comment: Add your GDAL commands to your question so others can test them. GDAL should not make any difference between VRT and physical files.

Comment: Your gdal command looks ok. Verify that both the shapefile and your tif files are in the same projection